# mysql SELECT past updates only

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql db with a particular field, update_date, that has a unix timestamp format in.   Some records have update_date in the future, some in the past.

I want to select all records that appear in the past only.

I was trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE update_date < NOW()
```

which doesn't work as NOW isn't using unix time so I'm trying to figure out how to make use of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function that I've seen for mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE update_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

You can also refer [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22106) to show the Unix_Timestamp getting current date in unix timestamp format.